# How are image widths determined in a bootstrap design?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, width, image-size

This may sound strange, but I don't understand how designers determine the image widths in their bootstrap layouts.

Consider the following template:

http://startbootstrap.com/templates/blog-post/

The 900x300 placeholder image is clearly not 900 wide on desktop 1080p monitor.  It only ever gets shown full size when the browser is around 1000px wide.

**Q) Am I being dense here? How are these widths determined/decided upon?**

This is important as I want to make some designs using bootstrap, but obviously I want to make sure I select appropriate image widths.

Comment: Usually I take the column width (8.33333333%) and the maxed out .container (1170px) == col-8 is 70% (8.3333 x 8) 70% of 1170px is 820px (rounding up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this, but simplest is to use Chrome's "Inspect Element".

1) Right-click on photo and choose "inspect element". Scroll down until you see diagram of it's dimensions, padding etc

2) Adjust browser width to max out photo width (in your example it's between 990px and 1200px)

2) Keep editing the the placehold.it image-width until the inspector diagram stops changing photo width (see attached photo). This tells you the max threshold, in this case is 940px.

[image: chrome inspector]

FYI, you can also try to determine knowing your column widths, padding, margins, and assuming you have properly reset nested column padding, but there is a lot of assumption and calculation there, so I tend to use the inspector method, at least to confirm.

Comment: If I am reading what you're saying right, your answer is based on the assumption that there is already an image present in the design.  Whereas I was asking in general about sizing up the images to go into the design.  Very helpful though, thanks.

Comment: Nope. I'm suggesting you use placehold.it images, like in your example. They're good placeholders, but in this case also great for determining ideal size.